# SuiteCRM, in the calendar under an appointment, the lead in the related area isn't clickable

Tags: php, jquery, sugarcrm, suitecrm

In Calendar, while assigning an event to a particular date, there is field named "Related to". When lead is selected from dropdown and i opted to choose from the list then there will open a pop-up containing all the leads.

What i want is to load some custom jquery whenever user select or change a lead from the leads list or whenever the input value changes.

What i have done so far is made a file called custom.js and included it on that page with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#parent_name').on('change', function(e){
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

The above code works file if i type something from keyboard into the input box but not working if i select the option form the pop-up list.

Please suggest the correct way to do this.

Please find the required info below:

- SuiteCRM Version 7.7.4
- Php Version: 5.5

[image]

Comment: Can you show the html of the elements? (by inspecting them with firebug or something)

Comment: This is the input field HTML: (in firbug) <input name="parent_name" id="parent_name" class="sqsEnabled yui-ac-input" tabindex="0" size="" value="" autocomplete="off" type="text">

Comment: And the pop up list ? the one that doesn't work

Comment: @Mawcel I have attached screenshot below. can't attach image in comment section. Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect and see html of **"Select"** button then you will see following code:

```
onclick="open_popup(document.CalendarEditView.parent_type.value, 600, 400, "", true, false, {"call_back_function":"set_return","form_name":"CalendarEditView","field_to_name_array":{"id":"parent_id","name":"parent_name"}}, "single", true);"
```

Therefore you have following two option of doing it:

1. Create New custom function: Create new function and change onclick to point to your new  function (`set_return_cstm`) as following:

`onclick="open_popup(document.CalendarEditView.parent_type.value, 600, 400, "", true, false, {"call_back_function":"set_return_cstm","form_name":"CalendarEditView","field_to_name_array":{"id":"parent_id","name":"parent_name"}}, "single", true);"`

2. Override return `callback` function:

   write your function in custom js file to override default fucntion and perform value assignment there.Study default set_return function for further detail. Following is the helping code:

   `function set_return (pData){
               console.log(" Parent ID =  "+pData.name_to_value_array.parent_id);
               console.log(" Parent Name =  "+pData.name_to_value_array.parent_name);
           }`

Comment: Thank you @star. this task is completed and client is fine with the solution which I had proposed, at the moment not remember exactly. will try to implement your solution for my self learning. Thanks once again.

Comment: yes, note that you need to change return function for these sort of activities. That is sugar/suite CRM standard.